# How to deploy Angular 6 with .NET Core 2.0 Web API Application to Microsoft Azure?

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-api-apps, azure-app-service-plans

How to deploy Angular 6 with .NET Core 2.0 Web API Application to Microsoft Azure?

I have created ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API (Server-Side app) application and inside that created Angular 6.0 app (Client-Side app). Both apps are build and running successfully in a local environment (Database - MongoDB: mLab server).

Now, I want to deploy an angular app with .net core web API app to Azure environment in a single web app service (where client app and server app (web API) will serve).

However, I deployed an angular app (client-side) to the Azure environment but not with .net.

Comment: I just recently wrote a blog about how to do this in very detail https://medium.com/@omikolaj1/complete-guide-to-deploying-angular-and-asp-net-33a0976d0ec1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know you ask about how to deploy both the client and the server in a single API app but you should create **two** Azure Web Apps:

1. An Azure **API App** that hosts your .NET core based Web API
2. A Azure **Web App** that serves your Angular application (most likely only contains static files) and probably consumes your API app.

This will allow you to deploy e. g. a fix in the API without the need to redeploy your UI. This also won't add additional costs since you can host both apps in a single App Service plan and will simplify your CI / CD process.

Comment: That makes sense !!. I will go with this approach